# HDR support has gone missing

Tags: windows-11, amd-radeon

I'm using two LG 27GL850 series monitors, wich support HDR10 mode. Earlier, when I was running my PC on Windows 10, using 6900XT GPU, it was possible to enable HDR mode and all worked as expected.

Now, soon after I've updated to Windows 11, with the PC configuration being the same, I've noticed that HDR support is gone in Windows display settings. It says, HDR mode is not supported by the monitors, which isn't actually the case.

Also, a while ago I've started noticing my PC's performance became not so great. In games the FPS is lower, on desktop it's web video stuttering. Maximized windows tend to display the default window border until I remaximize the window (for example, when I'm starting a game in maximized window mode). Contex menus and popup windows are blinking on appearance, it looks something like if it were switching its UI style between the defaut and its own custom style.

Overall it's all looking as if I was connecting to my desktop via RDP or something, like there is some virtual device in the display pipeline. Or maybe I overthinking it all.

Anyways, what do I do to at least restore HDR capabilities?

Comment: Have you installed the AMD drivers that support Windows 11?

Comment: @Ramhound of course, I even updated them today.

Answer (score 0):

So, after some trials and errors I have had partially resolved at least some of the issues. All of this appears to be a complex case, so no conclusive answer is possible, I believe.

To resolve HDR support issue I've used AMD cleanup tool and reinstalled the drivers clean. Performance issues then are partially solved by playing with the various performance options the drivers are providing (like anti-lag, chill, boost and others). The issues with windows borders and windows UI styles blinking, I suppose, are coming from Windows 11 itself since it's not yet perfected and known to introduce its own problems.